# functions returning char pointer

Tags: c, memory-management

I came across lot of functions returning char pointers in one legacy application.
Some of them returning pointers to local character arrays. It seems to be causing crashes after several invocations(not immediately!) see the usage below

```
char *f1(){
  char buff[20];
  char *ptr;

  ----
  ----
  ptr=buff;
 return ptr;
}

---
---

f2(f1());
```

f1() returns a pointer local variable and then passes it to another function. I got the crash directly when it's compiled using _DEBUG mode in MS DEV. But in release mode, it doesnt cause an immediate crash, but it might occur after making lots of such calls.

When I modified the usage as below, it's working without any issues. Is the following usage 
safe?

```
strcpy(arr,f1()); /* arr is fixed char array*/
f2(arr);
```

Answer (score 13):

No, it is undefined behaviour. It just happens to work in your case, but may stop working at any time.

Comment: And the reason it happens to work is that on the x86 the buff array is filled in from lower addresses to higher addresses and probably won't be touched by strcpy's stack usage. Don't do it anyway: Stack usage can vary because of asyncronous events like signals and interrupts.

Answer (score 3):

No that's is not safe. Just calling strcpy can modify the stack enough to cause problems later because the return address and parameters might over-write the array.

Answer (score 3):

the malloc solutions are interesting except that the memory should be free after usage. (outside the function). Else there would be a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

The f1 function is returning a temporary (buff) which is freed when the function returns. You need to use malloc() inside the function.

Comment: That would almost guarantee a memory leak with some unspotted reference to the function.

Comment: You could of course require a pointer to preallocated memory as an input parameter and have the function fill it, but then we do not have the same function signature anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Never return a pointer to local variable.  It may work in some situations, but in general you will have lots of problems with it.
Instead:

- document your function that it returns a pointer to allocated memory and that the returned buffer must be freed by the caller
- add a buffer and a size argument, and fill in the buffer (this is what is generally done in the Win32 API)
- if using C++, use std::string

Comment: I think two solutions for this.

1. use malloc inside f1(). In this case all callers should properly free memory after it's use. usages like
f2(f1()) should be avoided, because it doesn't retrun handle for freeing memory.

2. passing a allocated ptr to the function, so that f1() can copy the text in it. existing usages like f2(f1()) are not possible in this case as well.

which solution you prefer? Anyway it require lot of changes in existing application. because such patterns exists in several places. some of them allocates memory, but doesn't free it.usages like f1(f2(f3())) do exist.



2.

Comment: If by "never" you mean "unless the local variable is static", then I agree.

Comment: @William, if the local variable is static it will work (at least for a longer time).  But this doesn't mean it's a good practice.  If the function is re-executed before you made a personal copy of the returned buffer, you will still have problems.  Similar for multi-threaded applications (although you could use Thread-Local-Storage variables for that).

Answer (score 2):

> Is the following usage safe?

No.

If your function returns a pointer to anything, make sure it allocates a memory area and returns the pointer to it:

```
char *safe_f1(void) {
    char *ptr;
    ptr = (char *) malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    ...
    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe. The reason is simple:

Any variable on a function will be allocated on the stack whose memory is freed after the function returns. The fact that the memory is freed does not mean that its content is changed.

This means that the memory content you did put in the variable `char buff[20]` is still at the `buff` or `ptr` (since `ptr=buff`) memory position. Whenever you call another function (or execute another block), its function/block variables will go to the stack too, creating the possibility of changing the memory content for whose the position `ptr` points to.

In the `strcpy` example you wrote, you were lucky enough that the strcpy function variables did not get on the stack at a position that were inside the old `buff` array. This is the reason you got the impression that it was safe.

The conclusion is that there is no way you can really guarantee that a freed memory content of the stack will not change between two function calls.

The solution is to use `malloc` because `malloc` does not allocate memory on the stack but on the heap. Heap memory is not deallocated unless you chose to do so (by a free call).

This approach would guarantee that the memory pointed by `ptr` is safe to be used by any other function.

The drawback of this solution is intrinsic: once the memory is not deallocated unless you programatically do that, if you forget to free this memory and lose the content of `ptr`, this memory will be there, allocated for your program but never achievable, lost for as long as your program runs. This memory will become a memory leak :-)

This is one reason why some languages have garbage collectors... but this is another story :-)

PS.: I think that it is safe (if your program is single threaded), although I do not recommend,  to do something like that:

```
{
  char safe_buffer[20];
  char *unsafe_ptr;
  int i;
  unsafe_ptr = f1();
  /*Copy the buffer without calling any function
    not to change the stack content
  */
  for(i=0;i<20 && *(unsafe_ptr + i) != 0;i++)
  {
    *(safe_buffer + i) = *(unsafe_ptr + i);
  }
  *(safe_buffer + i) = 0;
  f2(safe_buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No..its still not safe.

At the time you are doing `strcpy(arr,f1());`, the pointer used as the 2nd argument is already  pointing to an array that does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

No, you see `buff[20]` is only available inside the `f1` function. To be precise, the memory is allocated on `f1`s stack.

You need to create a new `buff[20]` on the heap using `malloc` and return a pointer to that memory from inside `f1`. Another way is to create `buff[20]` outside f1 (from the function which calls `f1`) and send it as an argument to `f1`. `f1`can then change the contents of the buffer and doesn't even have to return it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best would be to modify f1() to use malloc(). Your solution isn't near defined behavior.

Comment: ok, then all callers to f1() should properly free it after it's use. right?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest two possible solutions:

1. Use a static `char buff[20]` in `f1` unless the function is called from multiple threads or the outside world stores the pointer beyond the strcpy.
2. Use `return strdup (ptr);` and `free` the pointer outside `f1`. This is easier to use than `malloc` (though technically the same). It's slower than 1. but thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing these functions to take a pointer that it uses

```
void f1(char *)
```

That way every piece of code calling the function has to make a decision about where the memory gets written to, and to delete any memory that gets allocated.