# C - Error when trying to pass a pointer to a function as an argument, can't get value

Tags: c, function, pointers, pass-by-value

I'm unable to pass a pointer to a function as an argument while successfully being able to display the value that is points to. The function checkIfPrime won't work or receive the values that the pointer pAr points to. Sorry for the messy code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int calculatePrime(){
    int i = 0, j = 0, z = 0, check = 0;
    int prime[100] = {2, 3, 5};
    int size = 3, primeNum = 7;
    int *pAr = prime;

    while (i <= 100){
        for (z = 0; z <= size - 1; z++){
            if (primeNum % prime[z] != 0){
                check++;
            }
        }
        if (check == size){
            prime[size] = primeNum;
            size++;
        }
        i++;
        primeNum += 2;
        check = 0;
    }
    return pAr;
}

int checkIfPrime(int *pAr, int num){
    int i, check = 0, isPrime = 0;
    int fail = 0;

    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Doesn't works here, *(pAr + 5): %d", *(pAr + 5));

    for(i = 0;i <= 45 && fail == 0; i++){
        if (num % *(pAr + i) != 0){
            check++;
        }
        else{
            fail = 1;
        }
    }

    if (check == 45){
        isPrime = 1;
        printf("\n%d is prime\n", i);
    } else{
        isPrime = 0;
        printf("\n%d is not prime\n", i);
    }

    return isPrime;
}

int main(){
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    int even[20], odd[20], prime[20];

    int num, temp;
    char str[20];
    int isPrime;
    int ar[45];
    int *pAr;

    pAr = calculatePrime();
    printf("Works here, *(pAr + 5): %d\n", *(pAr + 5));

    isPrime = checkIfPrime(&pAr, 7);
    //Having issues here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strongly suggest indent every line by 4 spaces, so all the code is seen as code.  Since the `#include` statements disappeared, please re-post them.

Comment: will do in second

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: (after the edit)  The function: `malloc()` is already prototyped in the header file: `stdlib.h` so no need for `#include <malloc.h>`

Comment: You're passing `&pAr`, which is an `int**`, to `checkIfPrime`, which takes an `int*`.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) Please consistently indent the code:  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces  2) insert a 'reasonable' space: inside parens, inside brackets, inside braces, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators. 3) insert a blank line around code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default`  4) Please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: regarding: `fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "your error message" );` to output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `printf("Doesn't works here, *(pAr + 5): %d", *(pAr + 5));`  The stream `stdout` is buffered, so only passes the data on to the terminal if:  buffer overflows, an input operation is performed, the newline '\n' is output, or the program ends.  Suggest adding a '\n' to the end of the format string

Comment: regarding: `for(i = 0;i <= 45 && fail == 0; i++)`  What is the meaning of the `45`?  it certainly has nothing to do with calculating primes

Comment: in function: `main()` regarding: `isPrime = checkIfPrime(&pAr, 7);`  Nothing is done with the variable: `isPrime` so why have it?

Comment: regarding: `FILE *fp = NULL;
 fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");`  Why have this code when nothing is using that `fp` variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [functions returning char pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341579/functions-returning-char-pointer)

Comment: The posted code causes the compiler to output 17 warning messages.  Then ends with: `Compilation finished successfully.`  However, all that means is the compiler applied some `workaround` to each of the noted problems in the code.  It does NOT mean the resulting code is doing the right thing

Answer (score 2):

`calculatePrime` creates an `int` array, `prime`, on its local stack.  The pointer returned from this function, `pAr`, is the address of this array.  However, the state of data allocated on the stack after the function has returned should be considered indeterminate.  That is, there is no guarantee, after `calculatePrime` has exited, that the data which `pAr` references will not be corrupted.

If you want to create data and return a pointer to it from a function, you need to dynamically allocate the appropriate space using a function like `malloc`.

Comment: I have allocated memory to the pointer pAr as such: pAr = (int*)malloc(45 * sizeof(int)); However I'm still unable to get it work properly

Comment: Are you still passing `&pAr` to `checkIfPrime`?

Comment: I am, I allocated it before calling the functions calcualtePrime & checkIfPrime btw.

Comment: But `checkIfPrime` takes an `int*` as an argument but `&pAr` is an `int**`.